# Is this question about programming software solutions for image cropping on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Is this question on topic here?

https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/29418/detect-face-then-autocrop-pictures

It has three up votes and 2 votes to close as off topic. I thought it would be worth bringing here to meta to discuss it before the comments heat up.

Personally I haven't voted on it either way, just wondering what the community thinks.

Comment: In the end, this did get moved to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 6):

I would not be inclined to close it immediately. The asker has a specific post-processing question they need answered. While their description of their current attempts includes a little bit of python scripting, "programming" is not actually the heart of the question. The heart of the question is automatically (I assume to do this in batch) identifying faces and cropping to just that face.

Just because this type of post-processing does not involve some point and click hyperfriendly user interface does not mean it is not legitimate photographic post-processing. I personally believe a little bit of scripting knowledge here and there can greatly improve even the average photographers post-processing options. As such, I am not inclined to close these types of questions as soon as they are asked.

This type of question would differ from a true programming question, wherein the asker is writing a program to do some kind of post-processing activity, for free or profit, and they need programming or algorithmic advice. Those cases would seem to be clear close and migrate targets, as they don't really have anything to do with photography or photographic processing.

In this case, I think we should leave the question open. We have a LARGE base of highly technical users here, and someone should either be able to help with the python side of things, or possibly throw out some imagemagic command line foo that could do the same thing, or a variety of other possibilities. It is also possible that someone will come along who knows of a friendly pre-packaged tool that will do the job as well. I'd like to see what comes up before even really thinking about whether this question needs to be closed.

So, in a nutshell:

- Programmatic Post-Processing: **On Topic!**
- Programming to create a post-processing tool: **Off Topic!**

Comment: Agree with jrista.

Comment: In the end, this did get moved to stackoverflow.