# Image Processing Questions on Topic?

Tags: discussion

It's been established that ["how do I do this with photoshop"](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1260/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-photoshop-and-similar-questions) Questions are Ok so long as they pertain to particular *photographic* goal.

It's also been established that [Photo Editing, Manipulation, and Image processing](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4220/are-image-manipulation-and-photo-editing-synonymous) are unique domains (or unique solutions to a problem.) and that any of those domains *might* be on topic here. Again it was hinted at in the

Finally, it appears that [programming questions are not necessarily off topic](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2606/is-this-question-about-programming-software-solutions-for-image-cropping-on-topi) so long as the question and correct answer pertain to photographic principles rather than programmatic issues

Where I still would like to see a bit of clarification is around image processing methods. For example, in [This question](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/96901/programmatically-assessing-image-quality) the OP has already photographically assessed the imagery and wants to know how handle the telemetry programmatically. I have an answer for him that involved Machine Learning but it doesn't really seem like a photographic answer... If none of us can think of a photographic answer does that make the question off topic? He is asking about working with images just in more of a statistical sense. Not to be too esoteric here but images are just a particular type of data array so it's hard to know where data analysis questions become off topic.

Further food for thought, I just answered [this question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/87789/segmentation-technique-for-handwritten-text-cursive-and-unconstrained/88497#88497) on CS SE and don't think it would have been considered to be on topic here. Does the fact that the CS question dealt with an non-pictorial subject somehow change the salience?

Sorry if this question is too nebulous. I'm happy to refine it based on suggestions

Comment: downvoted, meaning I don't think image processing should generally be on-topic here. DV in meta just indicates disagreement with the premise, à la yea/nay opinion. It's not a judgement of a good/bad question like in main: [Meaning of downvotes in Meta vs Main sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270/meaning-of-downvotes-in-meta-vs-main-sites)  =)

Answer (score 3):

There's already a good place for that question, and in retrospect, I should have voted to close it as off-topic, rather than too broad. The [Signal Processing (dsp.se)](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) Stack Exchange is the right place for it. It's all about algorithms for processing signals, such as 2D spatial data — that is, images.

The question, and therefore potential topical answers, wasn't about photography — it was about image classification and qualification algorithms. Sure, it's those algorithms would be *applied* to images, but meaty answers, and future answers looking to distinguish themselves from (theoretically) existing answers, are going down different algorithmic paths, not photographic paths involving the art and science of photographic creation.

Comment: Signal processing is so broad that image processing could get a bit lost there, and photography is naturally focused on images, so you could still get some questions here. For one thing, there is a lot of image processing baked into PhotoShop!

Comment: @KAE In the large, yes, the term _image processing_ spans a wide gamut. But the question wasn't whether _anything that can be called image processing_ is topical. The question was more _where's the line_ in the broad field of topics that are considered image processing. OP mentioned things such as "how handle the telemetry programmatically", which are dog-whistle terms synonymous with "off-topic" here (at least IMO). Questions primarily pertaining to image processing algorithms, implementation of them, etc., are fairly well off-topic here at Photo.se.